# Django, how to make multiple annotate in single queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

using Django 1.7, Python 3.4 and PostgreSQL 9.1 I am having difficulties with annotate over queryset.
Here is my model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES= (
        ('C', 'CREDIT'),
        ('D', 'DEBIT')
    )
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=False)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    available_funds = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, default=0.0)
    total_funds = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, default=0.0)
```

What I am trying to get is something like:

```
Customers:
Name    | Total in  | Total out | available funds   | total funds
-----------------------------------------------------------------
cust 1  | 255       | 220       | 5                 | 35
cust 2  | 100       | 120       | 0                 | -20
cust 3  | 50        | 20        | 15                | 30
```

and some data:

```
Payments:
amount  | customer  | type 
-------------------------- 
20      | cust 1    | D 
10      | cust 1    | c 
70      | cust 2    | D 
20      | cust 2    | C 
10      | cust 2    | D 
25      | cust 1    | C 
200     | cust 3    | D 
10      | cust 3    | C 
20      | cust 1    | D
```

i was trying this query set:

```
Customer.objects.select_related().filter(Q(payment__isnull=False)& Q(payment__type='D')).values('name').annotate(Sum('payment__amount'))
```

but i am getting only Debits.
I don't know how to create a list with customer,total in, total out, total funds, available funds.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting a limit of what you can do with a single queryset. The reason I say this is that you're asking to do database aggregation on different sets of `Payment` records.

Let's look at your current queryset:

```
Customer.objects.select_related().filter(Q(payment__isnull=False)& Q(payment__type='D')).values('name').annotate(Sum('payment__amount'))
```

Ignoring the extraneous `Q()` calls, the filter call `payment__type='D'` means that the payment_amount will always only pertain to debits. If you change that to 'C', it'll always only pertain to credits. This query demonstrates a fundamental constraint imposed on you by Django's queryset language -- you can't really generate two different aggregations and annotate them into a single record.

Taking a detour off to raw SQL land to see how I'd write this query is another way of demonstrating the point. You'll note, of course, that I still am running two different `Payment` aggregations here! One for credits and one for debits.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    customer
        INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM Payment WHERE type='C' GROUP BY customer_id, type
            ) AS credits
            ON credits.customer_id=customer.id
        INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM Payment WHERE type='D' GROUP BY customer_id, type
            ) AS debits
            ON debits.customer_id=customer.id
```

That query will return data approximately of the form:

```
customer.id | customer.name | ... | credits.total | debits.total
----------------------------------------------------------------
          1 |       foo bar |     | 20            | 30
          2 |       baz qux |     | 30            | 20
```

If you try to use only one inner join/aggregation, you're forced to have group by both payment type and customer, resulting in a table like this:

```
customer_id | type | sum(amount)
--------------------------------
          1 | C    | 20
          1 | D    | 30
          2 | C    | 30
          2 | D    | 20
```

When you inner join this intermediate result with your customers, it should be immediately clear that debits and credits still are not unified into a single record.

Because you can't do this sort of select with inner joins in Django (as far as I know), you can't really do what you're trying to do in a single query. However, there are solutions to your problem.

In descending order of desirability (in my opinion, of course -- and based on what I consider obviousness/maintainability of your resulting code), the first is to just do multiple queries and unify the results manually.

You can also track credits/debits as a part of the `Customer` record. You're already tracking available funds this way (you're using `F` objects in your query to update/maintain these records, right?), so it's not really too much more onerous to maintain credit/debit summaries in similar fashion as well.

Lastly, and I don't think you should do this as I don't think there's a burning need to, you can perform a raw SQL query to get the results you need in one go.